# Please suggest an Alternative of Fiddler Core 3rd party library

Tags: url, proxy, block, monitor, fiddlercore

I am developing an application in which I am monitoring the Internet traffic (using Fiddler Core) and if the the application finds the the URL not trust worthy then it do not let the user visit it.

Now as per Fiddler License and agreement I will not be able to use the fiddler core library.

Please suggest some other library or some code that can help me to monitor the internet traffic and blocking it if the URL is malicious.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. There is an open source project on Github named Titanium that helped me to achieve what I was trying to achieve from Fiddler core :P [Github project Titanium](http://github.com/titanium007/Titanium)

Comment: How you overcomed the firefox issue as titanium does't support HTTPS in firefox..

Comment: Check for the issue on the git repo. If you don't find one then raise one

Comment: Make a comment on the issue and subscribe. If they make any progress then you will be notified.

Comment: You can still download it here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/FiddlerCore/4.6.2

Answer (score 0):

Old question but since Titanium web proxy is unmaintained, you can use [fluxzy](https://github.com/haga-rak/fluxzy.core) which supports HTTP/2 and built with modern .NET.